# Custom criteria for subgrid view for Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

everyone! 
I have an issue with creating custom criteria for sub-grid view for Dynamics CRM.

I have 3 Entities, let's call them "Companies", "Customers", and "Surveys".

This is the hierarchy:
[image]

"Surveys" Entity has field "Score" that contain decimal score of Survey Responses.

On "Customer" entity I print a chart with avg score of customer Surveys:
[image]

test_C_1 is a Company name

test_B_1 is a Customers name

test_A_1 is a Survey name

But I need the same table + avr chart on the Company entity.
I successfully join the table, but I can`t filter the table for the current (selected) Company. I get the all results and the chart give me the wrong AVR score.
My wish is to get all "customers with all Surveys" that are related to the current Company.
[image]
What is the best method to clear the table from redundant information?

P.S. I need this for Dynamics Versions 7.0 and for the latest version 8.2.

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the "related records" functionality only jumps 1 level so it will only work on the customer entity. There are a couple of ways to work around this, but the easiest in my opinion is to denormalise the customer -> parent company onto the survey entity. So on survey you'll have a lookup to both the customer and the company.

Next, you can utilise an attribute mapping to copy down the parent company onto the survey. This will auto fill the survey -> company field when you create surveys from a customer record.

For the other times where surveys are created standalone (and you just select the customer manually) my recommended way to solve it is write a plugin (on pre-operation). The plugin will grab the parent company from customer record and populate it on the survey for you.

If you can't write plugins, a workflow that fires on create of a survey would suffice. It can grab the survey -> customer -> parent company and set the relevant field on the survey.

Once you have done all that filtering a grid / chart by related records should now work.

Another way, which I am not going to go into in much detail due to being slightly more cumbersome, is to override the FetchXML that is passed into a grid on the form... it works, but I think the plugin/workflow way is cleaner.

Comment: thank you very much :)
Could you recommend a plugin, please ?

Comment: If you don't have someone to write plugins, I'd recommend you write a workflow that runs on create of survey and on update of the customer lookup on a survey. Attempt the workflow first and if you have difficulties raise a new question for us to answer